Copying mesh modifications to other faces of a composite platonic solid
I've made a hollow dodecahedron model containing five inscribed cubes, it looks like this:

The next thing I want to do with this model is "braid" the star shapes formed by the cubes on each face of the dodecahedron, sort of like a Celtic knot. I want to make this braiding look exactly the same on each face and I have no idea how to copy such a mesh modification across faces given the different angles and different cubes involved in each face. If I make the mesh changes I want to make on once face, does anyone know how to copy these changes onto other faces? I'm pretty new to Blender and I have no idea how to approach this problem.

Each face is a shape repeated 5 times (a 1/5th of a pentagon if you will). And each face is identical to other faces. That means you can model one 1/5th of a face then repeat it. I'll try to write a full answer with a bit of not-too-hard geometry nodes. Is there anything inside the solid or is everything on the faces ?

That's a great idea! Each face has some thickness to it since I want to 3d print this model, but the solid is hollow inside that.
